# How to sort string with numbers in sql redshift in descending order?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to sort string column (containing numbers) but it doesn't work. Is there any way to do it?

```
+----------+
+-- name --+
+----------+
+-- W1 ---+
+-- W12 --+
+-- W2 ---+
+-- W3 ---+
+-- W53 ---+
+-- W52 ---+
```

This doesn't work. How can I make it work in sql redshift?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
order by name desc;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method for your data is to use `len()` along with the name:

```
order by len(name) desc, name desc;
```

This assumes that the prefix before the numbers is always the same length (and that the numbers are integers that are not zero-padded).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for numeric sorting and the strings have a differing number of number characters you will need to cast to a numeric type.  For example '3' comes after '10' when sorted (ascending) as text but 3 comes before 10 when treated as numbers.  In order to cast strings to a number types the strings must only contain number characters (0-9, . etc.).  So one way to do this would be to strip out all the non-number characters from the strings and then cast to INT.  regexp_replace() would be one way to strip the non-number characters though there are faster ways if the numbers appear only in specific patterns in the string.